# how to Drupal7 increase file upload size

Tags: php, file-upload, drupal-7

In my content type, my drupal 7 server is stating I have a 'current max limit 8MB' for file uploads. So I cannot change this to 128Mb as I want to.

But my web host php settings allow for 128MB uploads and in my config/media/file-settings I have set an upload of 128 MB uploads. In my settings.php file I have set 'ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M'); ' under PHP settings.

Why is my Drupal site not increasing the upload size, though I have set the increased upload size in all the file settings, the content type settings and php settings file.  There is no error message, but also no increase. What have I missed out, or what am I doing wrong?   How can I increase the file upload?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you @jwpfox. To clarify: Why is my Drupal site not increasing the upload size, though I have set the increased upload size in all the file settings, the content type settings and php settings file.  There is no error message, but also no increase. What have I missed out, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you set the field's max upload size. if yes try increasing it. if no then after changing the php.ini restart services (apache and php-fpm). and along with that change post_max_size also

Comment: yes I increased the field's maximum size upload but it made no difference. That's why I am posting the question, as i've set the PHP, the file upload settings and also the field settings but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add these lines to your htaccess file in your root directory.

php_value upload_max_filesize 128M

php_value post_max_size 128M